# What is the solution of $\frac{x^3}{y^3+z^3}+\frac{y^3}{x^3+z^3}+\frac{z^3}{y^3+x^3}=1$ in rational?

Tags: real-analysis, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, irrational-numbers

I have tried to solve the following equation in rational($x,y,z$ are rational numbers) $$\frac{x^3}{y^3+z^3}+\frac{y^3}{x^3+z^3}+\frac{z^3}{y^3+x^3}=1$$ , I can't find such pairs of rational numbers $(x,y,z)$ for which that function have solution , I have assumed $x=0,y=1$, I have got a complex solutions for z(unit complex roots) , I think it must to add another identity for which we have solution,And also I used $(1/(x+y+z))^3=1$ to excpand some terms in the titled identity but no result ? Any help ?

**Edit** I have added [this related link](https://mathoverflow.net/q/227713/51189) to this question which is provided by @Madara Uchiha in the comment

**Note**: The motivation of this question is to check whether we can write $1$ in sum  of cubic rational terms ,And I suspect if such solutions exist they must be large number

Comment: What is the source of this problem. Problems like this can be extremely hard, the source can help.

Comment: it is my own problem , I have created it by my self

Comment: This might be useful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MadaraUchiha,Thanks for the link am going to check it

Comment: Like Weierstrass form $\Biggl(-4\dfrac{x^3 y^3}{z^6}\Biggr)^3+\Biggl(-4\dfrac{x^3 y^3}{z^6}\Biggr)^2-\Bigl(4\dfrac{x^3}{z^3}\Bigr)^3=\Biggl(4\dfrac{x^3}{z^3}\Bigl(2\dfrac{x^6}{z^6}+\dfrac{y^3}{z^3}\Bigr)\Biggr)^2$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a roadmap to a solution; the details are too tedious for me to figure out.

First note that if $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Q}^3$ satisfies
$$\frac{x^3}{y^3+z^3}+\frac{y^3}{x^3+z^3}+\frac{z^3}{y^3+x^3}=1,\tag{1}$$
then so does $(kx,ky,kz)$ for every nonzero integer $k$, so it suffices to find the integral solutions to $(1)$.

Now suppose $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}$ is and integral solution to $(1)$. Then clearing denominators and rearranging a bit we see that
$$x^9+y^9+z^9+x^3y^3z^3=0.$$
Then setting $(X,Y,Z):=(x^3,y^3,z^3)$ we get the following cubic equation in $X$, $Y$ and $Z$,
$$X^3+Y^3+Z^3+XYZ=0,\tag{2}$$
and then using the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082249/transform-x3y3z3-3-mu-xyz-0-into-standard-form-of-elliptic-curve?noredirect=1&lq=1) as suggested in the comments, we can transform this to an elliptic curve with short Weierstrass form
$$Y^2=X^3+aX+b,$$
where
$$a=\frac{3085015005}{614656}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad b=-\frac{55345728797073}{240945152}.$$
Then [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/14/a/6) tells me that the corresponding minimal Weierstrass equation is in fact
$$y^2+xy+y=x^3-4x+6,\tag{3}$$
and that this elliptic curve has rank only the following five affine rational points:
$$(1,-1),\quad(2,2),\quad(2,-5),\quad(9,23),\quad(9,-33).$$
Of course equation $(2)$ has the obvious affine solutions (i.e. with $Z=1$)
$$(1,-1),\quad (-1,1),\quad (-1,-1),$$
that do not correspond to solutions to $(1)$, as they have $x^3+z^3=0$ or $y^3+z^3=0$.

Then there are two more rational solutions to $(2)$ with $Z=1$, and they can be made explicit by determining the rational transformation between $(2)$ and $(3)$. If these $X$- and $Y$-values of these two rational solutions are not perfect cubes, then the original equation $(1)$ has no rational solutions, which seems likely.

Answer (score -1):

**some idea**

If $(x,y,z) $ is a solution, then

$ (x^3,y^3,z^3) $ will necessarily  be a rational solution of

$$\frac{x}{y+z}+\frac{y}{x+z}+\frac{z}{x+y}=1$$

Comment: From [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/227760/51189I),I think no solution exist for n odd

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Here, the numbers are natural, not rational.

Comment: you are right , I didn't get attention for that

Comment: $1,2,3$ Viva l'Algérie.

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhh, are u algeria  like me ? Nice problem i don't know why it is not of interest here in SE

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Pas loin, from Morocco.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107487/discussion-between-zeraoulia-rafik-and-hamam-abdallah).

Comment: Thanks, Bon Ramadan.